# How to get Quantity to collect like terms?

Tags: units, algebra

In *Mathematica* numerical terms collect when their variables are equal.

```
.2 "SERC" + .7 "SERC"
(* 0.9 "SERC" *)
```

However, numerical `Quantity` objects do not collect.

```
Quantity[.2, "Megawatts"] "SERC" + Quantity[.7, "Megawatts"] "SERC"
(* "SERC" (Quantity[0.2, "Megawatts"]) + "SERC" (Quantity[0.7, "Megawatts"]) *)
```

I would expect these to collect into `Quantity[.9, "Megawatts"] "SERC"` but they do not. How can I make `Quantity` objects collect? My understanding is that they should collect in this instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is weird behavior on the face of it. You can force them to collect explicitly:

```
Collect[Quantity[.2, "Megawatts"] "SERC" + Quantity[.7, "Megawatts"] "SERC", "SERC"]

(* Out: "SERC" Quantity[0.9, "Megawatts"] *)
```

... or you can use `Simplify`:

```
Simplify[Quantity[.2, "Megawatts"] "SERC" + Quantity[.7, "Megawatts"] "SERC"]

(*Out: SERC Quantity[0.9, "Megawatts"] *)
```

The latter will also make the necessary unit conversions:

```
Simplify[Quantity[2, "Megawatts"] "SERC" + Quantity[700, "Kilowatts"] "SERC"]

(* Out: "SERC" Quantity[2700, "Kilowatts"] *)
```

Comment: `Collect` seems to be a good fit (+1).